# translating to c# code the use of a class method trough an object variable

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, object

I have just two years I started programming (mostly C#), but there's still a lot I don´t know about the language, I'm trying to translate a web project from VB.NET code to C# code, but I got to a section which I don't know how to translate.

The class in the VB code uses a sub procedure to do an INSERT to a database, to do this, in the class there is a db variable declared as an Object, then the db variable uses a function from a module to change the class type depending on the conection type and database is going to be used (this is determined from getting a value from the Web.config file), then after building the query, the db variable uses another function from the new class type assigned to execute the query.

To better ilustrate, here is the VB code.

This is the part where the db variable is used:

```
Public class MyClass1
   Private Sub _AddDB()
      Dim db As Object
      Dim query As String

      db = TypeDB()
      query = "Some Query"
      db.ExecuteDB(query)
   End Sub
End Class
```

As I said, the TypeDB() function is in a Module:

```
Module MyModule
   Public Function TypeDB() As Object
      Dim Str As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.GetValues("strConnDB").GetValue(0)
      Dim db As Object

      Select Case Str
        Case "SQL"
          db = New DBSql_Class
        Case "ODBC"
          db = New DBOdbc_Class
        Case "OLE"
          db = New DBOle_Class
      End Select
      TypeDB = db
   End Function
End Module
```

Each of the classes mentioned on the module has its own ExecuteDB function so there is no problems in executing the line db.ExecuteDB(query). I read that the closest thing to a Module in C# is a static class, so that was what I did with MyModule, I already have the rest of the classes, but when I try:

```
public class MyClass1
{
   private void _AddDB()
   {
      object db;
      string query;

      db = MyModuleClass.TypeDB();
      query = "Some Query";
      db.ExecuteDB(query);
   }
}
```

I immediately get the error that the db objetc does not contain a definition for the method ExecuteDB.

My first idea was to do a switch statement inside the _AddDB method, but it will not be optimal, because there is already a switch statement in the MyModuleClass to select the new type of class for the db variable, I tried searching for a solution, but all I found was only solutions that only uses one class.

I want to do this as close to the original project as posible, but this kind of interaction is all over the VB project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object-oriented clean solution to this problem in C# is to define an interface with ExecuteDB() operation and implement it in those three DB classes. Then return that interface from your static method, and then you can call it directly.

```
interface IDatabase {
  object ExecuteDB(string);
}

class DBSql_Class : IDatabase {
  public object ExecuteDB(string query) {
    ...
  }
}

static class MyModuleClass {
  public static IDatabase TypeDB() {
    switch(...) {
      ...
      return new DBSql_Class();
      ...
    }
  }        
}
```

Just a note: your class names are terrible. Please try to follow standard naming scheme when programming in .NET. :-)

Comment: I will try this, but the three DB classes already inherit from another class, can I add the inheritance from the interface?, as for the names, yeah, they are awful, but I'm in the office and they were the first names that popped in my head :)

Comment: I did some quick search and I see that I can have the inheritance from the other class and the implementation from the interface, I will try it as soon as I have some spare time

Comment: @G.Torres: Yes, technically, if they inherit a common base, you can make it abstract, add `abstract` method `ExecuteDB` to that base class. And then return type of `TypeDB` method can be that base class. But still from clean-code point of view I would prefer the interface. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare 'db' as dynamic in C# to achieve the same sort of late-binding that the VB code is doing.
e.g.,

```
  dynamic db = null;
  string query = null;

  db = MyModule.TypeDB();
  query = "Some Query";
  db.ExecuteDB(query);
```

Or, better yet, use the appropriate types instead of 'object'.

Comment: i didn't know about dynamic, I will try it, for the propper types I can't use them directly because I don't know which is the one that is going to be used, that bit is read in the Web.config file when the TypeDB function is called.